# How to open CAD files from Boardview?

Tags: software-recommendation, files, hardware, software-sources

I have a .CAD file created in Boardview. I have tried using [OpenBoardView](https://github.com/OpenBoardView/OpenBoardView) and it's very good, but it's basically for .BRD files not .CAD files.

Is there something like [BoardViewer](http://boardviewer.net) (which is written in .NET) for Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Please [edit] your question to add information, don't  use "Add comment" Comments are an "Us to You" channel, used to help you make your question better, and more likely to receive an appropriate answer. What does `file *.BRD` tell you?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant `file *.CAD`.

Comment: Are you sure `.cad` is a Boardview file?  From what I can find online, `.cad` has nothing to do with Boardview

Comment: @ThomasWard Well, i'm not sure, but some Boardview Motherboards are .CAD file, and openboardview can't read that file, so i got to go to windows and open that file with Boardviewer.net and it works, but i don't want to go to Windows!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... OpenBoardview.

OpenBoardview already supports multiple boardview formats and is not limited to `.brd`. Its introduction and documentation are outdated, someone should submit a documentation patch to clarify this situation.

As of 2022, the following format are supported by OpenBoardView: `.asc`, `.bom`, `.brd`, `.bdv`, `.cad`, `.cst`, .`pcbdoc`, and `fz`, which can be confirmed by reading its [source code](https://github.com/OpenBoardView/OpenBoardView/blob/master/src/openboardview/unix.cpp#L103C1-L111C52):

```
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[aA][sS][cC]");
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[bB][oO][mM]");
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[bB][rR][dD]");
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[bB][dD][vV]");
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[bB][vV][rR]");
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[cC][aA][dD]");
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[cC][sS][tT]");
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[pP][cC][bB][dD][oO][cC]");
gtk_file_filter_add_pattern(filter, "*.[fF][zZ]");
```

Support for `.cad` boardview files has been [added into OpenBoardView by Pull Request #137](https://github.com/OpenBoardView/OpenBoardView/pull/137) since Apr 26, 2019, and it has been released as part of [OpenBoardView v8.0](https://github.com/OpenBoardView/OpenBoardView/commit/5aab67e69994f6a029c03c6b8326d979354b009a). Thus, `.cad` files can be opened directly via OpenBoardView by default using the latest version.

If you have a `.cad` file that cannot be opened via OpenBoardView, it means it's probably another format but with the same extension name. I suggest you to open a bug report with a sample file and report the situation to the developers.